# Page Property Defined in Oracle Apex Does Not Display

Tags: html, oracle-apex

This is a follow-up to a discussion originating from another [oracle-apex](/questions/tagged/oracle-apex) tagged SO question where the author could not customize their Apex page with a variable `TITLE` value (the equivalent to setting the html `<TITLE></TITLE>` definition block).

The accepted solution posted under: [Changing Page Title Based on an Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659852/change-page-title-based-on-item-in-oracle-apex-4-0/24673291#24673291) suggests that using an "Apex substitution value" in the appropriate field should accomplish this:

[image: Using a Page Item Value to Define the Page Title Attribute]

If ***any*** value is set for the `TITLE` page property (substitution values, static literals, etc.), what can cause the setting not to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Troubleshooting Oracle Apex Page Display Settings and Attributes

A mocked up scenario would be where a defined page item is placed in the Page `TITLE` field, but the value does not show up when the page is "run".

> Excluding more obvious developer errors such as misspelled or inconsistently applied page item names, it is possible that there is nothing wrong at all... except that a custom application template/theme has excluded or accidentally left out the necessary html block from its definition: `<TITLE></TITLE>`.  This is easily searchable and confirmed by viewing the Application Theme or Template defined under the `SHARED COMPONENTS` section.

### Considering the Effect of Custom Developer Assigned Application Templates...

Applying a custom PAGE typed template to an example where the page title does not display, we get an original templated html script, complete with placeholders for all the input data values that are a part of the output display:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
    <head>
        #HEAD#
        <title>#TITLE#</title>
    </head>
    <body #ONLOAD#>#FORM_OPEN#<a name="PAGETOP"></a>
```

Note the line: **`<title>#TITLE#</title>`**, without it, there would be no page title if this template were used.  To verify, the template script/html is rewritten and the  line is deleted.  The result:

**Modifying a Page Template**

[image]

**Associating the Modified Page Template to the Apex Page**

[image]

**Setting the Value for the Page Item Associated with the page title.**

[image]

**Trying to Set an alternate Value for the Page Item Associated with the page title.**

[image]

No matter what value is set to the associated page item, the page attribute of "TITLE" does not populate (see the title of the tab associated with the demo pages).

> Page templates and output rendering processes are possible places to look first when troubleshooting a missing attribute already defined within the application design.

### Using an Alternate Page to Set the HTML `TITLE` Page Property

If the problem is not with a custom template or if the template selected is a default or Oracle "standard" template, there are other considerations:

This is the design layout of a "broken" Apex page where the html TITLE property is defined by a page level item that exists on the same page:

[image: Design Layout of an Incomplete Variable Page Title Definition]

1. The Display Attribute of the Page is set with a substitution value referencing a page level item defined on the same page:  `&P12_PAGE_TITLE.`.
2. For this example, the page level item `P12_PAGE_TITLE` is defined as a *Display Only* type.

If the page item `SOURCE` value is set to the "title" explicitly, this does not work. I figured out a working solution by setting the item, `P12_PAGE_TITLE` by using a `COMPUTATION` operation set up on another page.

This is the layout of the "testing" external page that sets the `P12_PAGE_TITLE` item value *before* the target page is redirected and the TITLE html property is rendered.

[image: Configuring a test data input page for Oracle Apex]

1. Set up a text box for free-form entry: `P14_PICK_PAGE_TITLE`
2. Make a form Button: `P14_SUBMIT_TITLE_CHOICE` with a `SUBMIT` action.
3. A `COMPUTATION` designed `AFTER SUBMIT` transfers the value entered on the test page (P14) and sets the value on the target page, P12.
4. A `BRANCH` action is defined to run `AFTER PROCESSING` (as well as `AFTER COMPUTATIONS` and `AFTER SUBMIT`)
5. The `BRANCH` action is set to trigger when the button defined in step (2) is selected.

This is the result:

[image: Data Input and Test Page for Customized Page Titles]

**The form designed on an alternate page for collecting the designated page title.**

[image: Target page displaying the selected title]

*This is the target page based on the selected title stored in the display-only page item displayed in the TITLE SELECTION region of the final target page.*

**Additional Discussion:**  `COMPUTATION` fields can assist with ensuring that page level items are assigned their value in advance of other page rendering activities.  Otherwise, the source or assigned data value is not read until after most of the page has been rendered.

> *When* a page item value is assigned/set is just as important as the data value put into it.